# SSRS report - generate PDF using url parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I am not using a report server, but rather the ReportViewer. Can I still generate a report and automatically convert it into PDF?

Thanks

As suggested here is more info.
This is web application, the backend is an ASP.NET code. The is from SQL database. The backend prepares all the data and creates report datasets.

Comment: in short yes, the report viewer control has an export button. If you need more, I suggest you expand you question to include what versions of any relevant applications/components/libraries etc that you are using.

Comment: I am not using any libraries. Are you asking for VS Studio version? It is 2019. Latest Browsers, that's it. My question whether I could generate the PDF using url parameter format:PDF

Comment: EDIT your question to include all relevant info. Is this a web app?, desktop app?, the version of the report viewer control?, where are you getting data from? What have you tries so far?. I doubt you will be able to call a url though (maybe others know more than me, this is not my area of expertise) as there won't be a service to call without an SSRS service running on the server but you can render in memory data to the viewer control and then export.

Comment: This is a web application. Not sure about the report viewer control version. The data is from SQL database.  When you say, render in memory data, what exactly do you mean? Is it in the Browser?

Comment: Please EDIT your question instead of using comments to add more info.